# logic issue in nested if in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

I have the following data (see below) from a dataframe called **dateCount.df**.

You can see that record number 19 is a Sunday and the previous record is from Friday. I am trying to write a nested if else statement that will take Friday, Saturday, and Sunday nrec field values and average them and replace Sunday's nrec with that average. It is not working for record 19. Can anyone spot the mistake in the logic in my nested if else?

```
suns = which(format(dateCount.df$Date, "%w") == 0)
for (i in suns) {
    # this first "if"  should check if the prior date Date[i - 1]  in dateCount is equal to the actual day before  Date[i]-1  and same for Friday
    if (i <= 2 && dateCount.df$Date[i - 1] == (dateCount.df$Date[i] - 1)  && dateCount.df$Date[i - 2] == (dateCount.df$Date[i] - 2)) {
        dateCount.df$nrec[i] <- (dateCount.df$nrec[i] + dateCount.df$nrec[i - 1] + dateCount.df$nrec[i - 2]) / 3
    }
    else {
        # this "if" should check if the prior date Date[i - 1]  in dateCount is equal to the actual day before  Date[i]-1  but not checking about Friday
        #because to get into this block of the embedded if one of the 3 conditions failed and I am now dealing with missing Friday data
        if (i>=2 &&  dateCount.df$Date[i-1] == (dateCount.df$Date[i] - 1)) {
            # this should be the case where Saturday is available but not Friday, so add and divide by 2
            dateCount.df$nrec[i] <- (dateCount.df$nrec[i] + dateCount.df$nrec[i - 1]) / 2
        }
        else {
            # this "if" should check if the prior date Date[i-2]  in dateCount is equal to the actual day before  Date[i]-2  but not checking about Saturday
            #because to get into this block of the embedded if one of the 3 conditions failed  and also the case where Saturday is available but not Friday
            # and I am now dealing with missing Saturday data but Friday is available.
            if (i <= 2 && (dateCount.df$Date[i - 2] == dateCount.df$Date[i] - 2)) {
                # this should be the case where Friday is available but not Saturday, so add and divide by 2
                dateCount.df$nrec[i] <- (dateCount.df$nrec[i] + dateCount.df$nrec[i - 2]) / 2
            }
            else {
                if (i >= 2) {
                    # this should be the case where neither Friday or Saturday is available so do nothing
                    dateCount.df$nrec[i]<-dateCount.df$nrec[i]
                }
                else { 
                    dateCount.df$nrec[i]<-dateCount.df$nrec[i]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data:

```
           Date  nrec  DayOfWeek
--------------------------------
 1    7/17/2011   220        Sun
 2    7/18/2011   267        Mon
 3   10/29/2009    30        Thu
 4   10/30/2009   212        Fri
 5   10/31/2009   238        Sat
 6    11/1/2009   424        Sun
 7    11/2/2009   423        Mon
 8    11/3/2009   268        Tue
 9    11/4/2009   445        Wed
10    11/5/2009   331        Thu
11    11/6/2009   241        Fri
12    11/7/2009   236        Sat
13    11/8/2009   332        Sun
14    11/9/2009   421        Mon
15   11/10/2009   399        Tue
16   11/11/2009   323        Wed
17   11/12/2009   358        Thu
18   11/13/2009   238        Fri
19   11/15/2009   301        Sun
20   11/16/2009   439        Mon
21   11/17/2009   374        Tue
22   11/23/2009   145        Mon
23   11/24/2009   472        Tue
24   11/25/2009   331        Wed
25   11/26/2009   327        Thu
26   11/27/2009   261        Fri
27   11/28/2009   296        Sat
28   11/29/2009   461        Sun
29   11/30/2009   514        Mon
30    12/1/2009   656        Tue
31    12/2/2009   505        Wed
32    12/3/2009   535        Thu
33    12/4/2009   331        Fri
34    12/5/2009   213        Sat
35    12/6/2009   444        Sun
36    12/7/2009   483        Mon
37    12/8/2009   225        Tue
38    12/9/2009   386        Wed
39   12/10/2009   102        Thu
40   12/11/2009   301        Fri
41   12/12/2009   375        Sat
42   12/13/2009   458        Sun
43   12/14/2009   332        Mon
44   12/15/2009   526        Tue
45   12/16/2009   515        Wed
46   12/17/2009   459        Thu
47   12/18/2009   312        Fri
48   12/19/2009   330        Sat
49   12/20/2009    34        Sun
50    1/16/2010    63        Sat
51    1/17/2010   238        Sun
52    1/19/2010    12        Tue
53    1/20/2010   481        Wed
54    1/21/2010   671        Thu
55    1/22/2010   439        Fri
56    1/23/2010   448        Sat
57    1/24/2010   648        Sun
58    1/25/2010   708        Mon
59    1/26/2010   695        Tue
60    1/27/2010   617        Wed
61    1/28/2010   499        Thu
62    2/25/2010   189        Thu
63    2/26/2010   551        Fri
64    2/27/2010   441        Sat
65    2/28/2010   716        Sun
66     3/1/2010   877        Mon
67     3/2/2010   758        Tue
68     3/3/2010   767        Wed
69     3/4/2010   721        Thu
70     3/5/2010   504        Fri
71     3/6/2010    36        Sat
72     4/5/2010   105        Mon
73     4/6/2010   885        Tue
```

Comment: There is a preview when you type a question in so you can see if it's going to look like gibberish before you post. Please edit if possible to fix it up.

Comment: So you're saying record 19 should change to (238+301)/2 and record 6 should change to (212+238+242)/3? But the friday and saturday values stay the same? Can you also provide the output you expect? That would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issues is your based on your `which` statement and how you are using the `for` statement.  The `which()` should give you the row indices (numbers) for rows that are Sundays, so that would be : 1,6,13,19,...

Your `for` statement will give you the same values for  `i`, so the first run through the loop will give you `i=1`, the second will give you `i=6` etc.

So when you test  `if (i <= 2 && ...` only the first value of  `i` will meet the `<=2` requirement, the rest won't do this part of the test. So row `19` hits the first `else` statement even though it has data for  Friday.

Maybe the first `if` should have the condition of `i>2` so that you just ignore the first tw0 rows?

*** Edit after reading comments ***

After failing the first two `if` statements, day 19 hits:

```
if (i <= 2 && (dateCount.df$Date[i - 2] == dateCount.df$Date[i] - 2))
```

19 is greater than 2, so it does not meet this requirement. I think you need to switch it to be `i>=2`. It might be simplest to start with

```
if( i<-2) {do something - This is when a Sunday if the first or 
           second day of the data}
else{
     if (dateCount.df$Date[i-1] == (dateCount.df$Date[i] - 1)).... etc
```

And just keep you same code, but delete all of the parts comparing `i` to 2 as you took care of that first.

Comment: Hi. Yes the value for row 19 should be (238+301)/2. The value for row 6 would be (212+238+424)/3

Comment: I think row 19 should not pass the first criteria because it does not meet this part: dateCount.df$Date[i-1] == (dateCount.df$Date[i]-1). So it will go into the 1st else block. Then it will not meet the next if statement for the same reason and so it will go into the next else block. As I see it, it should pass the next if test: i>=2   && (dateCount.df$Date[i-2] == dateCount.df$Date[i]-2). And so the assignment should be: dateCount.df$nrec[i]<-(dateCount.df$nrec[i]+dateCount.df$nrec[i-2])/2. But that does not seem to be happening.